# Ubuntu occasionally hangs even with low CPU load, free RAM and free space available

Tags: 16.04, performance

Sometimes my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (i3 and 4GB RAM) system hangs so badly that I cannot copy paste text.

I normally have System Monitor open to monitor my usage, and when I check it I find that I have enough resources for hang-free usage.

[image: System Monitor shows CPU load 5-10% with only 1 spike >50% and around 50% free memory]

What should I inspect? System Monitor seems unreliable? I have enough HDD free space.

---

Hard Drive specifications

Command: `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`

Result:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-121-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===

Model Family: Western Digital Blue Mobile
Device Model: NDC ND10JPVX-7SJC3T0
Serial Number: WXC1A17AD6CD

LU NNN Device Id: 5 0014ee 607557602
Firmware Version: 02.01A02

User Capacity: 1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]

Sector Sizes: 512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical

Rotation Rate: 5400 rpm

Device is: In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is: ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)

SATA Version is: SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)

Local Time is: Fri May 4 09:48:31 2018 IST

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Comment: Well, you are swapping.  What does top show for memory usage?

Comment: ill try to get that screenshot when it hangs. its difficult to take details when it hangs bad. will still try.

Comment: to add in more points, it mostly happens after I have some heavy [Graph Database](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/graph-database) operations that hangs and I kill those processes.

Comment: Is the OS 32 bit or 64 bit?  What about the Graph Database?  Regarding taking a screenshot, you could take a photo with your phone, or SSH in from a different system and leave top running.  That way, you could take  screenshot of the terminal (or even copy and paste the terminal text) on the non-hung system.

Comment: Its a 64 bit  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (i3 and 4GB RAM), I generally do some heavy processing of [Apache TinkerPop library](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/) on [NEO4J DB](https://neo4j.com/). Then it takes up all the RAM and a lot of swap memory, and many times processor.

But then I kill all the processes that of Java then the System Monitor reports a drop in usage, and it looks like the load is low. but some how for 5mins+ my System becomes very un-responsive.  I'll try the mentioned things to get more details.

Comment: Do you have an nvidia card and if the system hangs can you do a [Ctrl][Alt][F1] run  `top` in  irix mode and can you confirm `xorg` is hitting 100% ?

Comment: I had similar symptoms years ago when I only had 1GB of RAM, and Chromium used it up, and started churning swap.  Even more recently, with 16GB of RAM, I would have similar symptoms when JavaScript on some web page would consume all available memory.  Now I ulimit Chromium so greedy tabs just crash and die.  Have you tried turning off swap?  I never use swap.  IMO, swap just hides memory exhaustion, and then by the time you notice it, your system is hung.  With zero swap, clean program crashes are much more likely (as opposed to total system freezes).

Comment: add HDD info https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JI9y.png

Comment: my normal average use is using 3gb ram (out of 4) and using 1.6gb swap (out of 4gb). So I cannot limit swap percentage or disable swap, since I just dont have enough Hardware to support the system. could be your answer about swap is correct, but my hardware is limiting the potential solutions

Comment: Fyi, according to the following post, swap is 100,000 times slower than RAM for random access tasks:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371400/how-much-faster-is-the-memory-usually-than-the-disk  So upgrading your RAM or renting a VM with 8GB of RAM is, IMO, a very worthwhile experiment.

Comment: I think at the end of the days its the **swap** to blame because I am an under-powered system being running a lot of stuff, and the only way this can be fixed is upgrading h/w as suggested.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has many possible answers:

What type of hard drive does the computer has?

If you have a regular HDD what's making your system to hang is the swapping process, the OS is using hard drive memory to store information that should be stored in RAM.

If you're using a SSD drive swapping is also slow but not as much as the first case. Check your 'swappiness' by reading /proc/sys/vm/swappiness file, default is 60, you could try changing it to 10 (or even less) and see what happens. This way the system will swap only when 90% of the RAM memory is busy.

From : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

> **swappiness**
>
> This control is used to define how aggressive the kernel will swap
>   memory pages.  Higher values will increase agressiveness, lower values
>   decrease the amount of swap.
>
> The default value is 60.

To change the swappiness level your need to run this command:

```
echo 10  | sudo tee --append  /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

You can also try lower values.

If nothing works, you should consider upgrading to 8 GB RAM or running heavy processes on a cloud virtual machine (AWS, Google Cloud, etc.)

Comment: added HDD info https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JI9y.png

Comment: Your hard drive is really slow!  You have a 5400 rpm drive.

Comment: Let me know if you have any improvements changing the swappiness level.

Comment: first attempt of disabling swapping meant almost all of 4gb RAM was used, going to try a few more things of percentage threashold

Comment: my normal average use is using 3gb ram (out of 4) and using 1.6gb swap (out of 4gb). So I cannot limit swap percentage or disable swap, since I just dont have enough Hardware to support the system. could be your answer about swap is correct, but my hardware is limiting the potential solutions

Comment: Yes, nowadays 4 GB it's a very small amount of memory. My cellphone has more RAM. I can't work properly without at least 12 GB. Any chance of updating your hardware?

Comment: Did not get my problem solved, but considering all the comments and answer, I think at the end of the days its the swap to blame because I am an under-powered system being running a lot of stuff, and the only way this can be fixed is upgrading h/w as suggested. Thanks all.

Comment: 4GB of ram is enough for regular computer usage if you are not going to open an insane amount of browser tabs. Your cell phone is probably running more bloatware and background apps and services than a regular computer.